# FreeMarker: Expected a boolean, but this evaluated to a number

Tags: java, template-engine, freemarker

I have a template in which I do:

```
<#if result.numFound > 10> 
  (some data)
</#if>
```

This gives me parse error:

```
For "#if" condition: Expected a boolean, but this evaluated to a number
```

`result.numFound` is `Integer`. 
I've read the [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html), maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: I recommend you take a look at rythm template engine, check how easy it is: http://rythmengine.org/doc/directive.md#if

Comment: No worries, coz I am the author of this product ;-). BTW, you can have online experience with http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/

Comment: You can use `[` and `]` instead of `<` and `>`. It is much better in my opinion. To use `[` and `]` just start your template with `[#ftl]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You missed that last couple of lines in the documentation :).

```
How to test if x is greater than 1? <#if x > 1> will be wrong, as FreeMarker will 
interpret the first > as the end of the tag. Thus, either write <#if (x > 1)> or <#if x &gt; 1>.
```

Comment: It looks like I missed them ideed... I wrote this a week ago, but I'll write it one more time - I hate mondays. Thanks! :)